# Why Is My Image not floating next to my paragraph with the image i created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I've literally tried everything possible from removing absolute positioning from the class, to removing one element.

The problem I want my new image I create in JavaScript to blend in and take the place of my current image. However, when it doesn't it sits on top of the image and i UNDERSTAND its because of the absolute positioning..... the problem with that is that if remove the absolute positioning the image that's created fades next to it. I've tried almost everything!!! Can someone help? Also when I upload my JSfiddle the second image doesn't appear so i took snapshots of whats going on when I attempt different options. Please help!

```
Here is my jfiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/23w8ufLd/16/

[This is what i want to happen but the problem is that the paragraph isnt floating next to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcUR.png)

Comment: what do you really want your image to be?? please clarify your question

Comment: you want to have image side by side you and have text ?

Answer (score 0):

You almost there.

So i fix your CSS

**CSS**

```
.img-container{
    float: left;
    //height: 220px; i remove the height
  overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Full DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yh33ratz/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Fiddo93 no not at all..... i literally put a picture of whats happening in my question.....if i could email you screenshots that would help as this is driving me insane..Again I want the image i created in javascript to FADE into the place of the old image....however when i put the exact same code from my text editor into Jfiddle it doesnt appear so i understand why its rather difficult to get what i mean.

Comment: have you follow my css ?

Comment: ? i dont understand what you mean however i did upload what is going on and put link... @fiddo93

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yh33ratz/embedded/result/ 
but this demo look it's working. really weird

Comment: @CheckLife copy paste my css code

Take a look on this another demo i'm using different images. https://jsfiddle.net/m7p5ehcx/

Comment: yeah so i just found out that you have to put the javascript in the html for it to run...but that still actually not what i want to happend....however i did figure it out....here https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/y5md2weu/12/

Comment: its okay. Thanks though.